# Where does Jenkins clone the git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I created this simple pipeline where I am pulling a bitbucket repo -

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout from bitbucket') {
      steps {
        echo "Hello World"  
        git branch: 'feature/myFeature', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'my_bitbucket', poll: false, url: 'https://username@bitbucket.org/IT_AEM/infrastructure.git'
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

When I run the build, it succeeds. Where is the git repo downloaded in Jenkins and where can I view it?

[image]

Cheers

Comment: if you are too lazy,run pwd command as the next step,and you will get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your repo is cloned to your workspace in default. `$WORKSPACE` environment variable contains this path. You can define the workspace in configuration of nodes. You can see some details about workspace in this post: [Inconsistent Jenkins workspace path on slave machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933989/jenkins-workspace-path-on-slave-machines)

Answer (score 2):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554955/11373824):

> Jenkins clones git repository to the job workspace in `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/<JOB_NAME>/workspace`

And as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791873/11373824) you can modify this path:

> After adding a new git repository `(project configuration > Source Code Management > check the GIT option`) to the project navigate to the bottom of the plugin settings, just above *Repository browser* region. There should be an *Advanced* button. After clicking it a new form should appear, with a value described as *Local subdirectory for repo (optional)*. Setting this to `folder` will make the plugin to check out the repository into the folder relative to your workspace. This way you can have as many repositories in your project as you need, all in separate locations.